# The Kraft and McMillan Inequalities for Infinite Codes

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I have a copy of the Jones and Jones [Information and Coding Theory](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/556835) book. It states the Kraft inequality for instantaneously decodable codes and the McMillan inequality for uniquely decodable codes, both involving codes with a finite source alphabet. The proofs involve the maximum codeword length, which will not exist for infinite codes. Do these results hold for infinite codes? Does anyone know of a textbook with these results for infinite codes?

Edit:
Do the Kraft and McMillan theorems hold for infinite codes (codes with an infinite source alphabet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a proof of the Kraft–McMillan inequalities in [1, Theorem 2.4.12, p. 75].

[1] J. Berstel, D. Perrin, C. Reutenauer, *Codes and automata*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 129. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2010. xiv+619 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-88831-8

EDIT. You may prefer reference [2], in which Kraft–McMillan inequality is stated and proved on page 12, Formula (1.4).

[2] M/ P. Béal, J. Berstel, B. H. Marcus, D. Perrin, C. Reutenauer, P. Siegel, [Variable-length codes and finite automata](https://hal-upec-upem.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00620817/document). Selected topics in information and coding theory, 505--584, Ser. Coding Theory Cryptol., 7, World Sci. Publ., Hackensack, NJ, 2010.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I really don't like this book. It uses a lot of non-standard terminology for coding theory and abstract algebra. I can't even figure out if its statement of the Kraft-McMillan theorem is equivalent to the one I am familiar with.

Comment: @Jeff I disagree with you about the non-standard terminology in abstract algebra, but I added another reference which you will probably find more accessible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do appreciate it. However, I don't think the second source is what I'm looking for. At the beginning of section 1.4, they define alphabets as being finite, and thus their codes are finite codes. Their first statement of the Kraft-McMillan inequality looks like it is proven for both finite and infinite codes, but the converse is only stated for a finite number of positive integer word lengths. The proof also uses induction, and so it would not be a proof for an infinite set of positive integers, right?

Comment: The fact that the alphabet is finite does not imply that the codes are finite. For instance $\{a^nb \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ is an infinite prefix code.

Comment: You are viewing a code as a set of codewords (this was the view of Berstel's book). I view a code as a function C : S -> T+ from a finite/countable source alphabet S to the collection of non-empty sequences T+ coming from some finite code alphabet T. The alphabet S must be infinite to have an infinite collection of codewords (i.e., the image of C). In Béal's paper, all alphabets are finite.

Comment: "_There is a converse statement for the Kraft–McMillan inequality: For any sequence ℓ1, . . . , ℓn of positive integers such that [Kraft's inequality holds], there exists a prefix code C = {c1, . . . , cn} over A such that |ci| = ℓi. This can be proved by induction on n as follows._" **Variable-length codes and finite automata**.   I'm interested when the number of integers is countably infinite.

Comment: In the book, the proof is given for an infinite sequence. Just take the union of all $X_n$ at the end. Your comment on the finiteness of the alphabet is irrelevant. If you take $S = {\Bbb N}$, you can define $C \to \{a, b\}^+$ by $C(n) = a^nb$. This is a transparent translation.

Comment: My comment on the finiteness of the alphabet is not irrelevant. Béal seems to only be working with finite codes, and my question concerns infinite codes.

Comment: Just read the article in depth and then the book.

Comment: The article defiantly does not help. The book seems promising aside from its non-standard terminology (seriously, who refers to the identity element of a monoid as a *neutral* element? and who describes codes as monoids?).

Comment: About the use of the word *neutral*, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutral+element).

Comment: Identity element is more common by that logic and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=identity+element).

Answer (score 0):

First note that the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{N}$ since we can use the *zigzag* mapping whose beginning is given by the array below:

\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \\ \hline
1& 1 & 2 & 6 & 7 & 15 & \\
2& 3 & 5 & 8 & 14 & & \\
3& 4 & 9 & 13  &  & &  \\
4& 10 & 12 &  &  & &  \\
5& 11 &  &  &  & &  \\
\vdots & &&&&
\end{array}
Therefore it is enough to talk about encoding natural numbers instead of encoding sequences of natural numbers.

There are a number of source codes for integers, the most efficient are Elias' $\gamma$ and $\delta$ codes, the most straightforward but least efficient is the unary code. All these codes are prefix codes and obey the Kraft inequality.

$\textrm{Unary}(n)=1^n 0$

$\textrm{Binary}_k(n)=k~\textrm{bit representation of } n$

Codeword length of the unary code grows too fast for practical use but still satisfies Kraft inequality.

The Golomb-Rice code(word) for any $k\geq 0,$ and any $n$ is given by

$$\textrm{GR}_k(n)=\textrm{unary}(q)\cdot 
\textrm{binary}_k(n-q2^k) $$
where $q=\lfloor n/2^k \rfloor,$
where $\cdot$ is concatenation. Here are some examples that also include the Elias codes:
[image]

Comment: This does not answer my question. I know that there exist infinite prefix codes. I want to know if a prefix code must exist for any countably infinite collection of word lengths satisfying the Kraft inequality.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I suggest you edit the question so that it is precisely stated.